# How to we make the PopUpMenu to stop after showing in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have a problem while showing the `PopMenu` control in VB.NET. Where as in VB6 after showing `PopUpMenu` control holds on the screeen event after we have code after that also. But when we convert that to VB.NET we get `ContextMenu.Show()` the control is not holding on the screen and executing the next statements. This statements has to execute after clicking on the menu item in VB6. This is not happening.

Can you help me regarding this?

Comment: Check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402943/is-there-a-way-to-show-a-blocking-winforms-contextmenu) out

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog()` would block the code but unfortunately `ContextMenu` Doesn't have that method. You need to use a `Form` to get this functionality.

Comment: Yes if we use the ShowDialog(). But it is of no use :-(

Comment: yes I found like write a method in that put the code after showing the context menu .In that context menu closed event call that method